# No character data is allowed by content model - XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Trying to validate a small xml I get the following error: no character data is allowed by content model.

This is my example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plats xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="1_e.xsd">
    <primer codi='3'>Caldo de verdures</primer>
    <segon codi='4'>Pollastre al forn</segon>
    <primer codi='7'>Spaguettis</primer>
    <segon codi='12'>Llus a la planxa</segon>
</plats>
```

And this is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="t_primer">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="primer" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="t_segon">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="segon" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="plats">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="primer" type="t_primer" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="segon" type="t_segon" />
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am not able to find where I am wrong and the code looks nice...

Comment: You are nesting the same type twice: According to your schema `t_primer`must contain an element `primer` instead of the string content.

Comment: Finally I found the solution, your comment has made me understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem solved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="t_primer">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="t_segon">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="plats">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="primer" type="t_primer" />
      <xs:element name="segon" type="t_segon" />
    </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```